# Is there a way to manipulate the color palette of an indexed PNG image in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, image-processing

Is there a way to alter and replace the color palette of an indexed image with JavaScript?

I am aware that I can draw the image to a canvas, iterate through each pixel of the image, and overwrite pixels individually. However, that seems like overkill to me, and I would like a cleaner solution.

I would be willing to use a library to accomplish this. Additionally, I am working with pretty small images, so the "overkill" method which I previously mentioned would not be infeasible if necessary.

Comment: Are you working with a file (how?), or is it your goal to draw the manipulated image?

Comment: @Bergi I am loading the image through JS with the Image constructor and I want to draw it onto a canvas.